# What is TAB in oracle10g why does not it display default table names for newly created user?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

If I login as "system" then it shows default table names(`select * from tab`).
But when I login as "jagan", if I run a query (`select * from tab`) it is not displaying...In order to display default tables from "jagan", what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT * FROM TAB will only show objects that have been created in the schema you are connected to (i.e. JAGAN): until you create some objects there will be none to see.

TAB lists tables, clusters, views and synonyms from the current schema.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides a number of other dictionary views that give more information:

- `USER_TABLES` - all tables owned by the current user.
- `ALL_TABLES` - all tables visible to the current user.
- `DBA_TABLES` - all tables.

To view other objects as well as tables:

- `USER_OBJECTS` - all owned by the current user.
- `ALL_OBJECTS` - all visible to the current user.
- `DBA_OBJECTS` - all objects.